# RewriteRule htaccess wordpress

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have migrated an old WP and the new one has different urls. I'm trying to get 'argentina-es' of this kind of url:

`http://example.com/dev/category/places/america-latina/america-del-sur/argentina-es/page/9/`

`/dev/category/[places|other|another-one]/[get-this]/page/1`

after category there are 6 options and the page/id is not always present.

The final url I want is this:

`http://example.com/dev/no-category/argentina-es`

Trying:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dev/category(.*)
RewriteRule ^([places|other|another-one]*)/(.*)/page http://example.com/dev/no-category/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteRule ^dev/category/(places|other|another-one)/(.*?)/([^/]+)/(page/[0-9]+/?)?$ /dev/no-category/$3 [L,R]
```

Comment: not working.... I have seen many solutions using ^/dev instead ^dev Do you know the difference?

Comment: @returnvoid starting with `^/dev` won't work here because this is in an htaccess file and the leading slash is stripped off before applying a rewrite rule. In a blank htaccess file on a default install of apache, [those rules do exactly what you're asking for](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lJRoB.png)